# Property alias for URL encoded form GET and POST for web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

While I would otherwise use `[JsonProperty("first_name")]` for a property in my action to specify an alias on a model property on a JSON request, in this particular case, I need to support a GET or a form encoded POST.

Is there a means of specifying that a particular property on my action model would be bound to a different request value, much like how JsonProperty would allow for this?

For example, if I have a query string of `?first_name=ryan`, and my class model has a `public string FirstName { get; set; }`, how can I specify this binding? Thanks.

EDIT: In case it's mentioned, no, I can't change the names of the input, as this is to support an existing request format that I/we have no control over.

EDIT 2: To clarify, this is for .NET **Framework**, not Core.